# How to determine the original coordinate using the mouse coordinate, the translation and the zoom scale?

Tags: c#, canvas, coordinate-transformation

I will ask for this problem without a specific programming language.

I have got a canvas control with the hability to do zoom and translating the view (dragging). I have loaded an image on the canvas and my objetive is to obtain the coordinate when I click the mouse on the canvas.

The event when I click on the canvas gives me the coordinate of the mouse (mouse_x,mouse_y), the translate measure (delta_x, delta_y) and the zoom (1.0 means no zoom, x > 1.0 more zoom, x < 1.0 less zoom).

When I click on the canvas without move the image and do zoom, the image coordinates is the same of the mouse coordinates. OK.

```
real_x = mouse_x;

real_y = mouse_y;
```

[image]

When I click on the canvas with the image moved but without zoom, the image coordinates is the the mouse coordinates adding the translate measure.

```
real_x = mouse_x + delta_x;

real_y = mouse_y + delta_y;
```

[image]

The problem is when I do zoom, I don't know which are the equation to get the original coordinates using the zoom value.

[image]

EDIT:

These 3 solutions do not work.

Code:

```
     void DrawLineOnDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
        var mouse_x = this._mouseDownPos.X;
        var mouse_y = this._mouseDownPos.Y;

        var delta_x = this.TranslateX;
        var delta_y = this.TranslateY;

        var scale = this.Zoom;

        var windowwidth = 1000;
        var windowheight = 500;

        // OPTION 1. IT DOES NOT WORK
        var real_x = windowwidth / 2 - (windowwidth / 2 + delta_x) * scale + mouse_x;
        var real_y = windowheight/ 2 - (windowheight/ 2 + delta_y) * scale + mouse_y;

        // OPTION 2. IT DOES NOT WORK
        var real_x = windowwidth / 2 - windowwidth / 2 * scale + delta_x * scale + mouse_x;
        var real_y = windowheight / 2 - windowheight / 2 * scale + delta_y * scale + mouse_y;

        // OPTION 3. IT DOES NOT WORK
        var real_x = windowwidth / 2 - windowwidth / 2 * scale + delta_x * scale + mouse_x * scale;
        var real_y = windowheight / 2 - windowheight / 2 * scale + delta_y * scale + mouse_y * scale;

        // Draw line from last clicked to new clicked position
        ...
   }
```

For example, using solution 2, when I click the first corner of the image to the opposite corner of the image with 0.4 of scale (zoom), the line is drawn far of the mouse position (when I do the same without scale (1.0) and without translation (dragging) the lines is drawn properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I forgot post the answer. This control has got a method that do the magic for you.

```
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Translates a point relative to this element to coordinates that are relative
        //     to the specified element.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   point:
        //     The point value, as relative to this element.
        //
        //   relativeTo:
        //     The element to translate the given point into.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A point value, now relative to the target element rather than this source
        //     element.
        public Point TranslatePoint(Point point, UIElement relativeTo);
```

Answer (score -1):

I assume that scale is applied from the center of the image. You need to know the original size of the image and the scale factor to calculate the new position of the image. It should be something like this:

```
real_x = delta_x + originalWidth*(1-scale)/2 + mouse_x
real_y = delta_y + originalHeight*(1-scale)/2 + mouse_y
```

Edit: info, that scale-origin is at center of window

```
real_x = windowwidth/2 - (windowwidth / 2 + delta_x)*scale + mouse_x;
real_y = windowheight/2 - (windowheight / 2 + delta_y)*scale + mouse_y;
```

2nd Edit: 
What are POS: and REAL from your screenshots? they appear to be identical.
I rethought the formula - not sure though that this is what you need:

```
real_x = windowwidth / 2 - windowwidth / 2 * scale + delta_x * scale + mouse x;
real_y = windowheight / 2 - windowheight / 2 * scale + delta_y * scale + mouse_y;
```

if that does not work, maybe you'll need to use "mouse_x * scale" and "mouse_y * scale".

3rd Edit:
could it be as simple as this:

```
real_x = (mouse_x + delta_x) * scale
real_y = (mouse_y + delta_y) * scale
```

or maybe "/ scale" instead of "* scale"?

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work.The zoom is applied to the center of the canvas, not to the image. delta_x and delta_y is the distance move by dragging.

Comment: Thank you again, but it does not work. I edited the main post to give more info. I added the code proposed by you.

Comment: I added another possible solution & a question.

Comment: It still does not work. I update the main post. I have uploaded a new capture with the values. I click from first corner of the image to the last corner of the image.

Comment: When translating/scaling: is only the content/image affected or does the canvas change its size aswell?

Comment: No, the canvas does not change, the canvas has got the same size of the parent control, and this is fixed.

Comment: I added a 3rd Edit to my answer.. maybe it's working now.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I tried that solution before.